# How can I put a column in SQL that shows a 1 if the value in another column is unique and 0 if it's duplicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to build a column that puts the value 1 if it's the first occurrence of a value in one row and 0 if it's not the first occurrence.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to check values in different columns or different rows ?. Yo say one thing on the explanation and another on the sample.

Comment: I added an image just to show what i'm trying to explain!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your logic. You have both 1 and 0 flag values for the a value, and 1 flag value for the b value (which is not repeated on other rows). Can you explain it ?.

Comment: Your image is unclear. Value 'a' is not unique. Why is it shown as both 1 and 0?

Comment: @dimerazor the image shows something completely different from what you asked. What do you *actually* want? Post an example as *text*, not as an image, show what you want if there are more than two items. Why should one of the rows have 1 instead of all of them for example? `All of them` can be done by checking a `count(*)`. `One of them` can be done with eg `LEAD` or `LAG`

Comment: Are you storing that calculated value in the table?  Or are you asking how to write a SQL statement that includes the calculated column?

Comment: I would like to have that 1/0 column in the table.

Comment: @dimerazor you can't have one as a default value. Those numbers are the results of queries. You still haven't explained what you want though. Why should one row have `1` and some other, with the same values otherwise, have `0`? What is the logic? There's no order in a table unless it's specified explicitly with an ORDER BY

Comment: If you want to store the 1/0 in the table, then (unless I'm misunderstanding the question) you would need to re-calculate the value for every record, every time a record in the table is added/updated/deleted.  And also recalculate the value for every record any time you wanted to change the logic behind the calculation.  For this reason, it's a best practice to avoid storing calculated values in a database.  There are scenarios where it makes sense, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.  Instead, I would look at exposing the calculated value through a view or stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a window function and CTE to assign a rownumber to each partition of "data" and then have flag set to 1 when rownumber is 1 else 0.

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/XLY13454)

This assumes:

- the filed to evaluate is called "Data"
- the 1st entry isn't considered a duplicate where all others are. 1st is tricky here as we've not defined an order so the first entry the system encounters will be treated as non-duplicate; unless we further define the order by in the window function; that non-duplicate could change from run to run.

.

```
With CTE AS (SELECT Data, Row_Number() over (partition by Data order by Data) RN 
             FROM TableName T)
SELECT Data, case when RN = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Flg
FROM CTE
```

Returns something like this given my sample data used:

```
    Data    Flg
1   A   1
2   A   0
3   B   1
4   B   0
5   B   0
6   C   1
7   C   0
```

Comment: I don't know why this would get any upvotes.  The `order by` clause is not stable and the answer does not address the fundamental issue in the question -- which is that the sample table has no column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: That assumes ordering is relevant.  perhaps it's just a table with repetitious values and they don't care which one they keep.  My attempt was to answer the question as it was asked.  It may not make a whole lot of sense.  and I did state the row selected could change from run to run

Comment: .  The question is:  "if it's the **first** occurrence of a value in one row and 0 if it's **not the first** occurrence" (my emphasis).  I think it is really clear that ordering is important.  As I say in my comment, the *upvotes* confuse me.  I understand your answer, but not why it would be upvoted.

Comment: I get your point; only the Author knows what they're after at this point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not possible to automagically set and update this value in the table. They'd have to be recalculated after every modification to the table and calculated columns *can't* refer to other rows, or execute full queries.

You can use a window function like `LAG` to check if there's a  previous value in a set according to the search order you provide exists or not, eg  :

```
declare @t table (data varchar(10))
insert into @t
values ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('B'),
    ('C'),
    ('C')


SELECT 
    Data, 
    iif( lag(1) over (partition by Data order by Data) is null,1,0) as Value
FROM @t
```

This will return :

```
Data    Value
A       1
A       0
B       1
B       0
B       0
C       1
C       0
```

`lag(1) over (partition by Data order by Data)` partitions the rows by the values in the data column and sorts them by the same value, essentially producing a random order. It then returns the "previous" value for that partition. For the first row, there is none and `LAG` returns `null`.

`iif( ... is null,1,0) as Value` checks the result and returns 1 if it's null, 0 otherwise.

If you want to store the changes to the table, you can use an updatable CTE :

```
declare @t table (data varchar(10),value bit)
insert into @t(data)
values ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('B'),
    ('C'),
    ('C');


with x as ( SELECT 
    Data,value, 
    iif( lag(1) over (partition by Data order by Data) is null,1,0) as Val
FROM @t)
update x
set value=val
from @t;

select * 
from @t
order by data
```

You could use a trigger on INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE to run that query on every modification and update the table. It would be better though to make all modifications and execute `UPDATE` only at the end

Answer (score 0):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  Your table does not have enough information to answer this question, once the table has been created.

If you do have such a table, you can use a query such as this to assign the value:

```
select value,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by value order by ?) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for a column such as `createdAt` or `id`, which specifies the ordering of the values in the table.

If you don't have a column that specifies the ordering, you could do this with a trigger that checks if the value already exists.  However, rather than writing a trigger, I would suggest creating the table with an `identity()` column or `createdAt` column (or both) to capture insertion order.